# How can I tilt a surface in polar coordinates with R

Tags: r, polar-coordinates

I have a matrix with polar coordinates. I would like to tilt it over an angle "alpha". How can I do this in R?

For instance, I have a matrix:

```
mat=diag(10)
theta=seq(0,90, length=ncol(mat))
phi=seq(0,360, length=nrow(mat))
```

When plotting my matrix with polar coordinates I have the following (I didn't add the function to plot it as it is too long but I can share it if required):

Polar plot of the initial matrix

[image]

Now I would like to tilt this surface by an angle alpha (let say 10°) along the plane 0-180° towards 0°. Thus if I plot the tilted surface the "red snake" should move towards 0°.
Shifting and rotating the matrix doesn't give me the desired output. Can anybody help? My first thought is to estimate the tilted theta and phi vectors but I'm not sure how to do this. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add the code and the data you used. People will be more inclined to help you when given the necessary tools to understand your question.

Comment: The data is a large matrix from a hemispherical photograph (and I'm actually trying to evaluate the impact of the tilt on the photograph). I don't think it makes sense to put it here as it too large. But I attempted to illustrate the problem with a  simple matrix "mat=diag(10)". And the code I use for plotting is actually available here: https://gist.github.com/timriffe/2877281